# dom4j: retaining html tags in output xml

Tags: java, html, dom4j

I am trying to create an XML document in my JAVA code.

One of the tags in this XML contains the HTML bold tags along with other text as its value.

I want to make sure that when this XML is rendered in the browser, the HTML tags are retained.

As of now, I see escaped characters in the output.

```
Document suggesterDoc = DocumentHelper.createDocument(); 
Element suggesterDocRoot =   DocumentHelper.createElement("Response"); 
String modifiedSearchQuery = "<b>" + "test" + "</b>"; 
Element title = DocumentHelper.createElement("title"); 
title.setText(modifiedSearchQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a Text node that happens to contain characters that need to be escaped (<). A `<b>` tag must also be an `Element`.

```
Document suggesterDoc = DocumentHelper.createDocument(); 
Element suggesterDocRoot =   DocumentHelper.createElement("Response"); 
Element title = DocumentHelper.createElement("title"); 
Element bold = DocumentHelpr.createElement("b");
b.setText("test");
title.add(b);
```

This works, but it gets kind of tedious to create HTML this way.

Update:

A trick that may work, is to create the HTML text using String manipulation, parsing it into a document and transfer the elements to the target document. Something like this:

```
Document doc = new DefaultDocument();
doc.add(new DefaultElement("body"));

Document fragment = DocumentHelper
        .parseText("<p>Some inline text with <b>highlighted</b> content</p>");
doc.getRootElement().add(fragment.getRootElement());
System.out.println(doc.asXML());
```

which prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body><p>Some inline text with <b>highlighted</b> content</p></body>
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But my search string can have more than one word, for example if the string is: "testing by tester", then i need to surround only the sub-string "test" with html bold tags

Comment: Yes, as I said, creating HTML this way is not optimal.

Comment: Can someone please help on this? I have tried to find workarounds but no success

Comment: I added an alternative suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this alternative approach. This works partially. When a string like "<b>highlighted</b> content" is used, a Document Exception is thrown. It seems its expecting a start and end tag for the string "content" also

Comment: ok, in that case, if i want to highlight only the sub string "test" for a string  "testing by tester", this approach will not work

Comment: Wrap your text in an arbitrary element, parse it, and add the content of the arbitrary element to your target element.